# Latex doesn't recognize cntformats.sty

Tags: packages, kpathsea

I downloaded manually cntformats.sty and put it in the directory exsheets. But Latex still doesn't recognize it and asks if I want to download it.
I tried several times to download it by changing the location of links through latex, but the message "not found" is always returned.

I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why didn't you install it with your distribution package manager? Both MiKTeX and TeX Live have it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which TeX distribution do you use? How did you install the package -- through a package manager or by manually copying various files into various directories? After copying the files to their destinations, did you update the filename database of your TeX distribution?

Comment: Thanks to you all for welcoming me and for your answers. I downloaded MikTex basic, but that file was missing. Also could you show me how to update the filename database?

Comment: You shouldn't manually add the file to the directories MikTeX has installed, I don't think. Better would be to use MikTeX's package manager to install the relevant package. Note that this is likely to happen quite a lot if you've only installed a basic set of packages. (Assuming 'basic' means roughly the same for MikTeX as it does for TeX Live.)

Comment: I am having the same problem, very similar error messages.

I use MikTeX and Texmaker and both have been installing packages on the fly with no hiccups until now with `exsheets` and `cntformats.sty`.

My code, which will not fit in this comment, compiles perfectly in overleaf.com but not in TexWorks or TeXmaker. I also downloaded the `cntformats.sty` files and manually put them in `exsheets` folder to no avail... Any more ideas?

Comment: @ WeCanLearnAnything: I reinstalled MikTex then from anew, then it started to add missing files on the fly. And then cntformats.cty was installed this time. One mistake I did the first time is that I manually put cntformats.sty in exsheets directory, but this is not the right place for it. I'll try to locate it in my pc and feed back.

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437), [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/), and – if those haven't helped – at [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/).

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything please have a look at the links in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

To put cntformats.sty manually, follow these steps:

-Go to program files-->MikTex2.9-->tex-->latex

-Inside latex create a folder and rename it cntformats, and inside it put cntformats.sty

-after that go to program files-->MikTex2.9-->bin ,

and double click mo.exe, click "Refresh FNDB", when this is finished, click Update Formats.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: @ clemens: I didn't see your comment before I submitted my answer. Thank you very much. That helps a lot.

Comment: @ clemens: Yes, I saw them indeed, this why I told that that helped a lot. And that still helps a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just got me a new error message: "Tasks.sty not found". Am I supposed to need another package to go with `exsheets`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything yes. The same is true for a lot of packages which is why most people simply install a complete TeX distribution…

Comment: @ clemens - What is a "complete TeX distribution"? I use MikTeX and TeXmaker. Is that not complete?

Comment: No, basic MikTeX contains a basic set of about 200 packages  out of roughly 5000 packages. (to be honest, i don't know the exact amount of packages that come with basic and complete)